# How can i find that UIButton is collide to UILabel in swift

Tags: swift

I am having the UILabel which have the Title month of the day.
at the below of the UILabel i have list of UIButtons which have title name  past one year dates.
Now, i want to change UILabel title month as the date is change.

 but i am not finding the right solution to get how can i find the collide between the UILabel and UIButton.
UILable and UIButton is in UIScrollview.

i have refer the UITouch and CollisionBehaviour. but i am not getting the right solution

[image]

Comment: on button Click just change the uiLabel text as uiLabel.text = "any thing"

Comment: But my requirement is while scrollup the uibutton at that time find what is the date on the UIbutton and from that find the month of that day and change it in the uilabel text. so i have to find the button and label collide at the stop of scrolling.

Comment: one thing you can do once your uibutton find month of that day just used dispatch async as    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {uiLabel.text = "any thing" }

Comment: but for that i have to find which button is collide with uilabel after scrolling is stop. sp that i can find the button and get the month of that day

Comment: You may get what's the top "button date" using the content offset of the UIScrollView...

Comment: u need to write your own logic . but my suggestion is why u are not using date picker?

Comment: because we cannot change the height of the datepicker and i want the height same as uiview.